# htaccess issue with adding variables to the URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm having a few issues with htacess.
I need to redirect a few pages but it seems the rules are conflicting.

I have:

```
RewriteRule ^doors/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ products.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L]
```

as a rule then I've got:

```
Redirect 301 /doors/door-frames-and-mouldings/hardwood-door-frames---exterior  http://www.domain.co.uk/doors/door-frames-and-mouldings&sub=hardwood-door-frames
```

The problem I'm having is that it is redirecting to the URL: `http://www.domain.co.uk/doors/door-frames-and-mouldings&sub=hardwood-door-frames?c=door-frames-and-mouldings&p=hardwood-door-frames---exterior` - so it is just appending the old variables into the new URL. Is there any way to stop this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix mod_rewrite and mod_alias rules. Do it via mod_rewrite rule only.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^doors/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ products.php?c=$1&p=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^doors/door-frames-and-mouldings/hardwood-door-frames---exterior http://www.domain.co.uk/doors/door-frames-and-mouldings&sub=hardwood-door-frames? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava. Can I just verify that is is supposed to read: `([^/.]+)` rather than `([^/\.]+)` in the first RewriteRule?

Comment: I used `([^/.]+)` because dot doesn't need to be escaped inside character class. `([^/.]+)` means match anything except `/` and `.`